# Store User object in session with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Based on my understanding, there are a number of different ways to retrieve the authenticated username in Spring Security.

I'm currently grabbing the username by included the `Principal` as a controller method argument:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView displayHomePage(ModelAndView modelAndView, Principal principal) {

  modelAndView.addObject("email", principal.getName());

  // Render template located at src/main/resources/templates/dashboard.html
  modelAndView.setViewName("dashboard");

  return modelAndView;
}
```

Does Spring Security offer an easy way for me to store the User object into the session so it can be easily retrieved by any controller method?

I want to avoid performing a DB lookup each time:

```
// Lookup user in database by e-mail
User user = userService.findUserByEmail(principal.getName());
```

I'm using Spring Security 4.2.

Comment: @MatejMarconak Retrieved by any controller method

Comment: You can do something like this: `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();`

Comment: Right, but what about getting the entire User object without performing a DB lookup?  I've updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: You can implements custom `UserDetailsService`, where you return custom `UserDetails` with data you need - this data should be then in principal.

Answer (score 9):

Spring Security provides you with a static method for quickly and easy access:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String name = auth.getName();
```

Or

```
User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
String name = user.getUsername();
```

Maybe you would like do this in a base abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseController {
    protected User getCurrentUser() {
        return (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }
}
...
public YourController extends BaseController {
...
}
```

**Update**

If you want to store the current authenticated user in session, then you need store only first time in a object as suggested by @gkatzioura.

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MySessionInfo {

    private User user;

    protected User getCurrentUser() {
        if (user == null) {
            user = userService.findUserByEmail(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal().getName());
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

You can inject this bean in yours controllers like

```
@Autowired
private MySessionInfo mySessionInfo;
```

You must take care about cases when user is not logged, but this is another problem.

Comment: How to add rights based on authority for this user in controller?

Comment: You also need to add a proxy mode, for example `@Scope(scopeName = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the methods that spring security provides to get basic information such as name, authorities and everything provided by the [Authentication.class](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html).

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
authentication.getAuthorities();
authentication.getName();
```

But if you want more information, using a session bean to store the information is also a good idea.

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class UserInfo { .. }
```